# Проверка данных

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Всем привет. Мне нужна проверка - Если пользователя уже добавляли в друзья, то выдаем сообщение "нельзя добавить"., а если ещё ни разу не добавляли, то показать кнопку добавления.

Я пробывал сделать так, но не выходит:

```
$myid = $userinfo["id"]; //мой id
$yourid = $_GET[id]; //id страницы на которой я нахожусь
$result = mysql_query("SELECT idUserFriend FROM friends WHERE idUserFriend='$yourid'") or die("Ошибочный запрос к БД".mysql_error()); //вывод из базы

    if ($result == $yourid) {
echo "Не добавить";
    } else {
    echo "Добавить";
    } //скрипт проверки
```

т.е. я хотел сделать так что бы если результат выдал все id которые его добавили и выбрал только ту в которой в строке **idUser** было совпадение с моим id.

Дамп базы:

```
CREATE TABLE `friends` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, //id добавлений
  `idUser` varchar(11) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL, //мой id
  `idUserFriend` varchar(11) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL, //id которого я добавил
  `avatarUser` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL, //мой аватар
  `loginUser` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL, //мой логин
  `loginUserFriend` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL, //Логин которого я добавил
  `avatarUserFriend` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL, //Аватар пользователя которого я добавил
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Дамп базы users:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `patronymic` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `mobPhone` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `homePhone` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `street` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `home` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `entrance` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `floor` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `apartment` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `avatar` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=5341;
```

Comment: А у Вас есть табличка users? Там где просто пользователи хранятся?

Comment: Да. Щас добавлю в вопрос

Comment: Типа такого ?


SELECT idUserFriend FROM friends WHERE idUserFriend='$yourid' AND idUser='$myid'

Comment: на случай если вы не в курсе

-----
[deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: @eicto не правильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитайте внимательно документацию, что возвращает mysql_query, посмотрите примеры использования...

`if ($result == $yourid)` так де проходит...

потому что, надо сделать что-то в таком ключе

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['idUserFriend'];
}
```

Comment: Просьба написать полный рабочий скрипт, т.к. я вас не понимаю, я только начал изучать php точнее даже не изучать, а просто писать функционал на php